# Film script for/from the novel

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was wondering which preposition - *for* or *from* - should be used in this case:

> I am conducting research on the film script **from/for** this novel. (meaning that the script is based on this novel)

Corpus search yields both variants, but I'm not sure whether they mean the same.

Comment: Try "based on:" "I am conducting research on the film script based on this novel."

Comment: I concur with @KatherineLockwood. The relationship between a novel and a corresponding screenplay seems sufficiently complex to call for a verb. Prepositions, though they are potent and versatile beasties, can't always do the job by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a coincidence, but this question was asked on [wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/film-script-for-from-the-novel.3261104/) yesterday.  The answer given there looks good to me, although the person who answered didn't document the answer, and I don't know how to document it either.  All I know is that I've seen it like this:

> My research involves a comparison of the original script *Title XX* and the film script from the novel *Title YY*.

I think it's because the novel was written first.  You start with plums and grapes, and from them you make prunes and raisins.

Answer (score 1):

...but if you novelize a film you might say "using the film script for a novel". Better to take the advice given by others above and say specifically what you are doing (in this case "writing a novel based on a film script").